# I'm trying to loop through and scrape a text file of links with BS4. I get an error at about the fourth iteration of the loop

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to loop through a list of links from a text file and write the info to a text file. I get the 'index out of range' error and I have no idea why.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def item(a):
    return a[::2]


def details(a):
    return a[1::2]


sFile = open('scraped_data.txt', 'w+')

with open('C:/Users/Main/Desktop/Python Web Scraper/link_list.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()


def scrape(l):
    r = requests.get(l)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    itemlist = []

    for items in soup.find_all('td'):
        itemlist.append(items.text.strip())

    for i in range(0, 6):
        print(item(itemlist)[i] + ' ' + details(itemlist)[i])


for i in range(0, 52):
    scrape(lines[i])

sFile.close()
```

**This is the console result.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cobus Uys/PycharmProjects/Scraper/Scraper.py", line 33, in <module>
    scrape(lines[i])
  File "C:/Users/Cobus Uys/PycharmProjects/Scraper/Scraper.py", line 29, in scrape
    print(item(itemlist)[i] + ' ' + details(itemlist)[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a `try/except` clause which will catch any errors and stop when iteration is complete.

You can also take advantage of adding extra `except` clauses and maybe use `else` or `finally` if appropriate.

In the function:

```
def scrape(l):
    r = requests.get(l)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    itemlist = []

    for items in soup.find_all('td'):
        itemlist.append(items.text.strip())
    try:

        for i in range(0, 6):
            print(item(itemlist)[i] + ' ' + details(itemlist)[i])
    except IndexError:
        print('Scraping finished')
```

in the for loop:

```
try:
    for i in range(0, 52):
        scrape(lines[i])
except IndexError:
    print('Scaraping Finished')
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you. If I understand this correctly, it basically ignores the errors until the looping is finished?(I am very new to this, sorry.)

Comment: In this instance. The only error will be an empty list which will throw the exception.  It means you can be sure the list is empty.  It also keeps a good error checking in place if you need to add extra except clauses